# Pointers to constants in C

Tags: c, pointers

I compiled the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    char *consta = "ABC";

    printf("Use of just const: %c\n", consta );
    printf("Use of const[1]: %c\n", consta[1]);
    printf("Use of whole string: %s", consta);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output that I get is:

```
Use of just const: P
Use of const[1]: B
Use of whole string: ABC
```

The second printf and the third printf function calls work as expected however, I was expecting 'A' to be printed instead of 'P' in the first call to printf.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour strikes again.

Comment: You need this: http://www.amazon.ca/C-Primer-Plus-5th-Edition/dp/0672326965  Are you currently enrolled in a course on C, or just teaching it to yourself?

Comment: The *printf* function is not type safe. Enable all warnings in your compiler.

Comment: `consta[0]` would give you `A`.

Comment: No Mr. Dogbert, not enrolled in any course on C. Self-teaching myself at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`consta` is a pointer to a character. The formatting specifier `%c`  expects an argument of type `char` (character)<sup>†</sup>, not `char*` (pointer to character). Your code exhibits undefined behavior. Try to dereference `consta` instead:

```
printf("Use of just const: %c\n", *consta);
```

where `*consta` is incidentially equal to `consta[0]`.

† Actually, the argument is of type `int` and is converted to `unsigned char`  by `printf()`. This has to do with argument promotion rules that apply to functions with variable arguments; an argument to `printf()` of type `char` is promoted to `int` before passing it to `printf()`, which is why `printf()` has to promote it back. For most programs the difference does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

`consta` is pointer containing the address of a string.

You're telling `printf` to treat that as a character, which is undefined behavior.  Pointers are usually implemented as storing the address as a number, so it will typically print the ASCII value of that address.

You want to pass the value at that address (which the pointer points to) by writing `*consta`.

Comment: `consta` is not a number, but a pointer. Also, you should really at least mention that the code has undefined behavior, and why, and what that means, before saying how it might play out with one specific implementation.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

```
char *consta = "ABC";
```

is a pointer to `char` pointing to `"ABC"`, to be exact to the 1st element of `"ABC"`, that is `'A'`.

"Pointing to" means `consta` contains an address, here the address of the `'A'`.

To print a pointer, will say an address, use the conversion specifier `%p`:

```
printf("Use of just const: %p\n", (void*) consta);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can spot three problems with your code:

1. The variable `consta` points to a constant string so you should to make it a constant:

   ```
   const char *consta = "ABC";
   ```
2. The second argument to the first print statement should be the first character in the string rather than a pointer:

   ```
   printf("Use of just const: %c\n", consta[0]);
   ```
3. In the last print statement there is no final newline. This implies that there may be no output from it.

If you want your code to be standard ANSI C conformant you also need to change the  line-comment (`//...`) to a block comment (`/*...*/`).

It is also a good idea to enable all warnings in your compiler. With the popular GCC compiler I use the following options:

```
-ansi -fsanitize=address -g -pedantic -Wall -Wfatal-errors
```

Comment: Isn't ANSI C the oldest standard of C? Shouldn't people keep up with a newer standard?

Comment: @AnasAyubi If you write in ANSI C you can compile your code with any current C compiler. This is not true for C99.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom don't the newer versions pack better efficiency and etc